# How to get Repositorytool.jar in Apache ACE?

Tags: apache, jar, download, repository, osgi

Apache Ace documentation refers about [RepositoryTool.jar](https://cwiki.apache.org/ACE/software-development-tools.html) that can be used to manage Repository. But I could not find this tool in the Apache ACE distribution. Where can I download this tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you're referring to is part of the old site (the new one is located at http://ace.apache.org), and refers to tooling you probably shouldn't be using anymore: it has been used before there were other ways to interact with the repository, mainly for development purposes.

Depending on your needs, you can use the repository in a number of ways,

- If you need to programmatically read and write the repositories (remember that they're only XML), use the [HTTP API](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/ACE/Object+Repository+Protocol) available for that.
- You can do the same thing from code, see [Repository](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ace/trunk/ace-repository-api/src/main/java/org/apache/ace/repository/Repository.java) and its implementations.
- If you want to edit 'meaningful' ACE data (such as linking distributions and targets), use the [Client REST API](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/ACE/Client+REST+API). This is probably the option you want.